# Single key not working on DIY mechanical keyboard (xd75re PCB and Switch both work)

Tags: switches, pcb-assembly, keyboard

I have assembled my first mechanical keyboard using the [xd75re PCB](https://m.aliexpress.com/item/32818745981.html?trace=storeDetail2msiteDetail&spm=2114.12010608.0.0.2995e5c0pd89Jw#autostay). I used a plate mount, and all of the switches were installed without issue (this PCB has hotswap). When I used keyboardtester.com to test the keys (after assembly), I found that there was one key that wasn't registering at all (from the factory, it was the letter 'D' in a qwerty layout).

**I tried the switch in other locations and it worked. I also shorted the contacts for the key using a paperclip, and it registered the letter ('D'). Yet, when I put the switch (or any other switch) into that location, nothing registers.**

I thought that the pcb might not be close enough to the plate for the switch to reach the contacts, but all the keys around it work and the plate is parallel to the PCB. Tightening the closest bolts made no difference holding the two together did not make the switch work either.

I'm at a complete loss for what to check next. Everything else about the PCB and the switches work perfectly. I am able to type on the rest of the keyboard and was able to flash the microcontroller without an issue.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE: None of the switches were properly seated (from inexperience generally and with hotswap in particular), which caused the plate to bend away from the PCB. After testing again, with the plate and PCB parallel and all the switches flush, the 'D' key still does not work.** I've re-checked the switch and the PCB, both work separately.

Comment: your description indicates that the problem may be with the plate mount ..... please post a picture of the D key area .... also post a picture of one of the keys so that we know what you are dealing with

Comment: This is **not** a forum.  If you have the answer **post it as an answer** in the space marked **answer** below your question.  Move the text in your "Solved" section to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hotswap for the particular key wasn't soldiered on one side, so it had nothing to do with my beginner mistakes.